# Java 8 Stream API to get specific value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Having the below JSON structured value. I would like to get the value from the "KEY" in List of Strings

```
"Test": {
    "ONE": {
      "First_Layer": {
        "KEY": "VALUE_1"
      },
      "First_Layer_1": {
        "KEY": "VALUE_2"
      }
    },
    "TWO": {
      "First_Layer_2": {
        "KEY": "VALUE_3"
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected Output (List of String):

```
[VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3]
```

Tried this and it is working with one layer, not with second layer

```
final Map<String, Map<String, String>> value = document.get("Test", Collections.emptyMap());
        return value.values().stream()
            .map(valueMap -> valueMap.get("KEY"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you please add what have you tried thus far? And also how is that JSON represented as a Java object?

Comment: @tdranv, JSON represents as org.bson.Document;  Updated which I tried.

Comment: It seems `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>` but you  are using `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

Comment: yes. I am able to get upto 2 layer; not able to get third layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should deserialize into `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`

Then you can use `flatMap` to flat the first layer

```
List<String> res = data
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.getValue().entrySet().stream())
        .map(v-> v.getValue().get("KEY"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```